# Listing and Tabular in Multicols enviornment

Tags: tables, floats, multicol

I want to use the multicols environment to display a listing beneath a table:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
   \begin{lstlisting}[]
 .....
\end{lstlisting}

\columnbreak

 \begin{table}
       \centering
     \begin{tabular}{r|c|c|c|c|c}
         .....
      \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
\end{multicols}
```

But this only displays my listing. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not a pair of `minipage` environments?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{...}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Play with the width of the `minipage`'s.

Answer (score 26):

The `multicol` package doesn't support normal floats, like `table` and `figure`, only page-wide floats, which are starred forms: `table*` and `figure*`.

But you do not need the `table` environment to create the table, that only causes it to float. You could replace the `table` environment with a `center` environment, or drop the surrounding environment altogether. If you need a caption, you can use the `captionof` command from the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,listings}
\begin{document} 
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{lstlisting}[]
      .....
  \end{lstlisting}
\columnbreak
 \begin{center}
     \begin{tabular}{r|c|c|c|c|c}
         a & b & c & d & e & f 
      \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!